# Создание списка кнопок с разными параметрами обработчика нажатия

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

Пытаюсь в цикле присвоить команды для каждой кнопки из списка buttons,
чтобы при нажатии в консоль выводились разные значения

Сейчас при нажатии на любую кнопку выводит 4.

В тройных кавычках показано как нужно, чтобы работало.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tic Tac Toe')

buttons = []

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        buttons.append(tk.Button(root, font=('Arial', 26), text=' ', width=7, height=3))
        buttons[-1].grid(row=i, column=j)

for i in range(len(buttons)):
    buttons[i]['text'] = str(i+1)
    buttons[i]['command'] = lambda: click(i+1)


'''
buttons[0]['command'] = lambda: click(1)
buttons[1]['command'] = lambda: click(2)
buttons[2]['command'] = lambda: click(3)
buttons[3]['command'] = lambda: click(4)
'''

def click(arg):
    print(arg)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```buttons[i]['command'] = lambda x=i: click(x+1)```

мне так больше нравится ))

спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

У вас `i` не становится локальной переменной лямбды, а является внешней глобальной переменной, из-за этого при нажатии на кнопку в функцию передается последнее значение этой переменной (значение глобальной переменной на момент нажатия на кнопку).

Чтобы "связать" конкретное значение внутри лямбды, можно передать его внутрь как значение параметра по умолчанию:

```
buttons[i]['command'] = lambda i=i: click(i+1)
# или buttons[i].config(command=lambda i=i: click(i+1))
```

или при создании

```
tk.Button(root, ..., command=lambda i=i: click(i+1))
```

(многоточие тут - просто пропущенные параметры, к себе в код его вставлять не нужно)