# Привязка обработчиков с разными параметрами для массива элементов управления

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при щелчке на любой label функция open_url открывает страницу с последним url в списке text.

Если по отдельности задавать label1, label2, ... ну не в цикле в общем тогда всё правильно, каждому label свой url.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
lbl = []

def open_url(url):
    webbrowser.open(url)

y = 0
for i in range(len(text)):
    lbl.append(Label(txt, text=text[i]['title'], fg='blue', cursor='hand2'))
    lbl[i].place(relx=0, rely=y)
    lbl[i].bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: open_url(text[i]['url']))
    y += 0.05
```

Вариант когда всё правильно

```
lbl = []

def open_url(url):
    webbrowser.open(url)

lbl1 = Label(txt, text=text[0]['title'])
lbl1.place(relx=0, rely=0)
lbl1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: open_url(text[0]['url']))

lbl2 = Label(txt, text=text[1]['title'])
lbl2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1)
lbl2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: open_url(text[1]['url']))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание списка кнопок с разными параметрами обработчика нажатия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966587/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Передавайте значение `i` через параметр лямбды, иначе внутри лябмды будет использоваться просто значение глобальной переменной `i` (одно и то же для всех):

```
lambda e, i=i: open_url(text[i]['url'])
```

или передавайте в лябмду сам url:

```
lambda e, url=text[i]['url']: open_url(url)
```