# Программа запоминает лишь самый последний процесс

Tags: python, tkinter, процесс

Есть вот такой недоделанный диспетчер задач на tkinter:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Splash")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(background='Grey')
root.resizable(0,0)
frame = Frame(root)
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    frameobject = Frame(frame)
    label = Label(frameobject, text=f"слитый працес: {proc.name()}", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=70, height=2, bg='black', fg='white')
    label.pack()
    m = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
    m.add_command(label =proc.name(), command = lambda: print(proc))
    
    def do_popup(event):
        try:
            m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        finally:
            m.grab_release()
    
    label.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)
    frameobject.pack()
frame.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

он должен вывести все активные процессы и при нажатии на них с пкм должен вывести контекстное меню в котором имя процесса, но место этого в контекстном меню не данный процесс, а как я понял последний в списке процесс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в цикле создается новое меню с одним элементом столько раз, сколько процессов. Выведите создание меню за цикл (выше цикла), в цикле добавляйте в него элементы. P.S. не только меню, но и фрейм внутри цикла у вас создается, его то же выше вынесите. Вообще, вынесите из цикла все, что должно создаваться один раз, а не по количеству процессов.

Comment: зделал как вы сказали, теперь при нажатии на какой либо из лейблов открываеться меню в котором все процессы, а мне надо чтоб при нажатии на лейбл правой кнопкой мыши в контекстном меню было лишь название прцоесса на который я нажал

Comment: Ну тогда в цикле нужно только общее меню создать, а выпадающее меню создавать только в момент нажатия правой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: я так и зделал если я вас правильно понял

Comment: У вас сейчас меню создается не в момент клика, а при старте программы. Нужно создание `m = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)` внести в саму функцию do_popup. Ну и скорее всего имя процесса нужно будет передавать в эту функцию через лямбду, примерно как тут, только имя процесса вместо i: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1007631/1365

Comment: думаю я так и не до конца понял что вы имели ввиду, можете пожалуйста предоставить ответ кодом?

Comment: Добавил ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import psutil

root = Tk()
root.title("Splash")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(background='Grey')
root.resizable(0,0)
frame = Frame(root)


def do_popup(event, proc):
    m = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    m.add_command(label=proc.name(), command=lambda: print(proc))
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()


for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    frameobject = Frame(frame)
    label = Label(frameobject, text=f"слитый працес: {proc.name()}", font=("Helvetica", 10), width=70, height=2, bg='black', fg='white')
    label.pack()
    label.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, proc=proc: do_popup(event, proc))
    frameobject.pack()
frame.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Процесс приходится передавать таким хитрым способом, потому что в вашем варианте функция видит глобальную переменную `proc`, которая на момент завершения цикла содержит последний процесс. Когда значение передается через параметр, оно становится локальной переменной функции, не зависящей от состояния внешней переменной.

В принципе, ситуация аналогичная [вот этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966587/1365), только при биндинге еще нужно принимать в лямбду и передавать в обработчик параметр `event`.

[image: Скриншот]