# Как в функции обратиться к кнопке созданной динамически передав ей параметр и изменив config

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно создав кнопки в цикле обратиться к их `textvariable` для проверки условия, а потом изменить ее конфиг. Что бы передать параметром `textvariable` проблем нет, а вот что бы изменить конфигурацию самой кнопки у меня не хватает опыта.

Пробовал через `bind.button("OnCklick", somefunc)` без передачи параметра через, в функции принимал, к примеру `name` далее через `name.widget.config` менял значение, но тогда не передается `textvariable`. И получается что я могу либо одно , либо второе. Код просто для примера:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

alice = StringVar(value="alice")
mark = StringVar(value="mark")
peter = StringVar(value="peter")


def some_func(parametr):
    if parametr.get() == "alice":
        button.config(bg="black")


for i in range(3):
    names = [alice, mark, peter]
    button = Button(tk, bg="white", command=lambda: 
some_func(names[i]), textvariable=names[i])
    button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Текст вопроса пишите в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1465110/edit).

Comment: Спасибо. Писал два раза текст там, сохранял, но он не появлялся, решил написать в комментарий. Возможно не там писал.

Comment: Изменение command у кнопки делается через `button.config(command=какая-то-функция)`, не через bind. Если нужно чтобы кнопка переставала работать, я бы кнопку блокировал через `button.config(state=DISABLED)`. Еще посмотрите информацию в этом вопросе и ответе к нему, возможно столкнетесь с этой проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966587/1365

Comment: Мне не нужно менять command. Дело не в этом. Изменение bg - это просто пример. Дело в том что бы обратиться именно к той кнопке ( созданной в цикле без уникального имени )  что была нажата , изменить ее config ( любой, цвет текста, bg, - не важно ) и при этом передать из этой кнопки в качестве аргумента ее textvariable для проверки условия внутри функции. То-есть по сути надо передать 2 аргумента. 1 передан в качестве "parametr" в примере который я выложил, а вот второй я не понимаю как передать. Можно через lambda привязать "i" например, но как обратиться к этой "i"-кнопке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример решения с передачей в `some_func` и текста (имени), и самой кнопки. Сначала создаем кнопку без указания `command`, потом через `config` значение `command` прописываем. При этом параметры в лямбду передаем через присваивание значений по умолчанию (`lambda name=name, button=button: ...`), тогда в параметры передадутся значения на момент привязки лямбды, а не последние значения переменных name и button на момент нажатия кнопки.

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

names = ["alice", "mark", "peter"]


def some_func(name, button):
    if name == "alice":
        button.config(bg="black")
    else:
        button.config(bg="green")


for name in names:
    button = Button(tk, text=name, bg="white")
    button.config(command=lambda name=name, button=button: some_func(name, button))
    button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я думаю что это примерно то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Кое-как нашел свой старый код. Вот какое решение я использовал

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

def foo(a):
    BTNS[a].config(bg = 'red')

names = ['alice', 'mark', 'peter']
BTNS=[]
for i in range(len(names)):
    btn = Button(root, text = names[i], textvariable = i, command=lambda a=i: foo(a))
    btn.pack()
    BTNS.append(btn)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хоть это немного не то, но теперь я вижу что можно обратиться к виджету как к элементу списка, никогда не думал об этом.